# Are Apple Push Notifications supported using .p8 key for Ad Hoc Deployment

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, provisioning-profile

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to push to my app and notifications are being delivered as expected in `Development` and `App Store` deployments. No notifications are being delivered for `Ad Hoc` deployments. I'm using `.p8` key, not `.p12` certs for delivery.

I've noticed that in the configuration for my app identifier in developer.apple.com, the info button indicates supported distribution types `Developer ID, Mac Adhoc, App Store`, omitting `Ad Hoc` which some of the other sections support

[image: Identifier Push Notification Configuration]

`Ad Hoc` and `App Store` deployments have `aps-environment:production` in `embedded.mobileprovision` and are signed by same `Distribution` certificate as expected. I recently replaced all of the Certificates and Provisioning Profiles as recommended in a few different places.

I've been watching the `apsd` process in the iPhone Console logs but have limited experience in what to expect there. Notifications are definitely not arriving but I can't tell whether it's an issue with registration or not. I get an FCM token in `Ad Hoc` app so I suspect it's not failing in `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` as is suggested in [Technical Note TN2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

1. Do push notifications work in `Ad Hoc`? (My searching indicates yes)
2. Where should I look next to investigate the issue?